# SharePoint 2013 - forms and workflows

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

We would like to use SharePoint 2013 Standard edition - to build Internet facing forms and workflows - in many cases the forms are filled in by anonymous users.

We can't use InfoPath since we do not have Sp enterprise to host web forms.

We don't want to buy Nintex, etc for other reasons.

We do want to use SP Designer to build workflows.

Should we use ASP.NET to build forms? If yes, is there a way to pass a link to the form from a workflow step - email with Context - I've been looking around and have not been able to find good tutorial or book describing this.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Dima.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you a right, you can use ASP.Net for your item and task forms. Moreover, [SP2013 WFs don't support InfoPath task forms](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/sharepoint-server-2013-known-issues-HA102919021.aspx).

Quote from the link above: "Workflow form changed from InfoPath form to ASPX form. Workaround: No workaround is currently available."

So now you can't use it even in Enterprise version.

In general, one of the ideas is to create content types and associate ASP.NET forms with them (to edit, view or create an item). In such a case it is also possible to email the link to this forms. You can take a look at the browser when it shows your custom ASP.NET form and I think you will understand how to create a link to it for your purposes.

Recently I have written an article about [custom ASP.NET task forms](http://sp2013-blog.com/2013/03/creating-spd-2013-workflows-part-23-implementing-custom-asp-net-task-form/). I hope it is pretty detailed and you get the idea. The idea for Item forms is the same.

Comment: ASP.net is definitely the way to go. More of a learning curve, but no unnecessary InfoPath restrictions. Not only is InfoPath not supported, but MS finally put the nail in the coffin: http://blogs.office.com/2014/01/31/update-on-infopath-and-sharepoint-forms/